# Natural Deduction Proof - Does this work?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

[image: enter imapracticingtion here]

I've been practising but I'm not sure of any means to check my work, can anyone point out if they're any mistakes in this proof?

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what is “subcomp” in your proof, and how you get 2.

I will not give you the detailed answer, because it looks like homeworks.

The theorem you would like to prove is a conjunction (AND), which means you have to prove both sides: P, and ¬Q.

To prove P, you will have to use reduction to absurdity (from ¬A if you can prove ⊥, then you can prove A), or another of its forms (excluded middle or double negation).

¬Q is easier to prove, just use the ¬ rules.